# Insert plain html/css/js pages and add address (route) to them

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Say I have html template https://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page244/debut How do I insert them into Drupal correctly so that it works exactly as I if've put these files from archive alongside Drupal...? So that if I open "mysite.com/contact.html" I get exactly the contents of contact.html an everything inside (links to css/js files) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding, you want to serve a static HTML file from the same domain as a Drupal site, and not bootstrap Drupal in the process, so the static HTML gets served directly. I'd recommend using the Pathed Files module (https://www.drupal.org/project/pathed_files) which lets you upload a static file or paste its contents into a form, and specify a custom URL for it. Alternatively, if you just put an HTML file in the Drupal files directory (e.g. `https://your.website.com/sites/default/files/your-html-file.html`), your Web server will happily serve it as is, but you have to live with that `/sites/default/files/` path in the URL. Truth be told, you could put it right in the Drupal Web root, alongside `index.php`, and the Web server will serve it without bootstrapping Drupal. But that's very ugly, and you really, really should not do that.

Comment: No, I know that I can put pages on server without any Drupal. But that's not what I want. I want, for example to use authorisation information from drupal, use abilities of twig for example. Or let those pages be not html but php files that output html but with ability to interact with  Drupal api inside them.

Comment: OK, so you want the Drupal theme system to actually be invoked for this page, but you want its contents to be static. Maybe you could create a dummy node in the Drupal to represent the page, then save your static page as `page--node--[node ID].html.twig` in your theme's templates folder. Drupal should serve it at the path for that dummy node. See also Drupal docs on template naming conventions: https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645

Comment: Wow, @rohnjeynolds that seems to sound what I need Could you please explain it in more details?

Comment: preferably with minimal example of, for example fully custom page with login/password fields?

Comment: Create a node in Drupal of any content type and give it dummy values. After you save it, you'll get the node ID. Save your HTML page in your theme's template folder, and name it `page--node--[node ID].html.twig`, where `node ID` is the ID of your dummy node. Clear caches, and when you go to the URL or URL alias for that node, Drupal should serve your page template. The link I shared before explains how template naming conventions work.